# Google Maps and jQuery Tabs and Size show

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-tabs

I have problem with Google maps included in simple jQuery Tabs to show.

if data in tabs have many line show simple jQuery have scollbar , how auto size tab ?

Below I pasted the code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Default Action
$(".tab_content").css({'visibility':'hidden'  , 'position':'absolute'});
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
$(".tab_content:first").css({'visibility':'visible' , 'position':'static'}); 

//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".tab_content").css({'visibility':'hidden' , 'position':'absolute'}); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).css({'visibility':'visible'  , 'position':'static'});
    return false;
});
```

});

if I pasted the below code , simple jQuery auto size tab but google map show a mistake.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//Default Action
$(".tab_content").hide();
$("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); 
$(".tab_content:first").show(); 

//On Click Event
$("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
    $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    $(".tab_content").hide(); 
    var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); 
    $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    return false;
});

});
```

I really don't know what to do to. Is that a general problem with google maps or there is something with my tabs?

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm editing and susses

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Default Action
    
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show();
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); 

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(".tab_content").hide();
        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        if(activeTab == '#tab2') {
            $(window).resize(function(){
            //$("#tab2").css({'display':'block'});
            //$("#map_canvas").css({'width':'630px', 'height':'400px'});
            //initialize();
            //alert('Changed!');
            });
            }
        return false;
    });
});
```